# How to add image for all posts associated to specified category?

Tags: categories, images, post-thumbnails

simply i want to add image beside every post depend on the category something like that
http://network.smashingmagazine.com/

you will see there is an image beside every post, i want it to be related to category, so i can upload an image for this category and all posts under this category will take this image

did any body see plug-in do this job ?

thx advanced for all

Answer (score 1):

Here are two plugins which might be useful for you:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-images-ii/

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/categories-images/

it is so simple and so easy, you can find everything in documentation :)

Comment: Hi, Muhammad, welcome. We collect solutions, not links, please explain *why* this plugin will answer the question.